# Very fast rolling hash in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, hash, sha256, rolling-computation

I'm writing a toy `rsync`-like tool in Python. Like many similar tools, it will first use a very fast hash as the [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash), and then a SHA256 once a match has been found (but the latter is out of topic here: SHA256, MDA5, etc. are too slow as a rolling hash).

I'm currently testing various fast hash methods:

```
import os, random, time

block_size = 1024  # 1 KB blocks
total_size = 10*1024*1024  # 10 MB random bytes
s = os.urandom(total_size)

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(len(s)-block_size):
    h = hash(s[i:i+block_size])
print('rolling hashes computed in %.1f sec (%.1f MB/s)' % (time.time()-t0, total_size/1024/1024/(time.time()-t0)))
```

I get: 0.8 MB/s ... so the Python built-in [`hash(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) function is too slow here.

**Which solution would allow a faster hash of at least 10 MB/s on a standard machine?**

- I tried with

  ```
  import zlib
  ...
      h = zlib.adler32(s[i:i+block_size])
  ```

  but it's not much better (1.1 MB/s)
- I tried with `sum(s[i:i+block_size]) % modulo` and it's slow too
- Interesting fact: **even without any hash fonction, the loop itself is slow!**

  ```
  t0 = time.time()
  for i in range(len(s)-block_size):
      s[i:i+block_size]
  ```

  I get: 3.0 MB/s only! So the simpe fact of having a loop accessing to a rolling block on `s` is already slow.

**Instead of reinventing the wheel and write my own hash / or use custom Rabin-Karp algorithms, what would you suggest, first to speed up this loop, and then as a hash?**

---

Edit: (Partial) solution for the "Interesting fact" slow loop above:

```
import os, random, time, zlib
from numba import jit

@jit()
def main(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-block_size):
        block = s[i:i+block_size]

total_size = 10*1024*1024  # 10 MB random bytes
block_size = 1024  # 1 KB blocks
s = os.urandom(total_size)
t0 = time.time()
main(s)
print('rolling hashes computed in %.1f sec (%.1f MB/s)' % (time.time()-t0, total_size/1024/1024/(time.time()-t0)))
```

With Numba, there is a massive improvement: 40.0 MB/s, but still no hash done here. At least we're not blocked at 3 MB/s.

Comment: Recomputing the hash for the entire block each time is not a "rolling hash".  You calculate a full hash *once*, then for each step you update that calculation using only two bytes of data - the one that just exited the block at the start, and the one that just entered the block at the end.  This is incompatible with most hash functions, but is trivial if you are using the sum or XOR of all the bytes.

Comment: @jasonharper even with a loop with a sliding window and *no hash*, it's already slow (2.4MB/s). The only way I found is Numba for this (see updated question at the end).

Comment: Your loop is still making a block-sized slice of the data at each step - that's a huge amount of data being copied around for no reason.

Comment: @jasonharper I think `block = s[i:i+block_size]` makes no copy, it's just a reference/view to this block, is this right?

Comment: I don't think any built-in Python types create views into the existing object when sliced (that's a somewhat problematic approach - it's all too easy to run into memory problems due to tiny slices keeping the original objects alive).  You'd have to use `numpy` to get that behavior.

Comment: @jasonharper I just updated the question in "Interesting fact": `for i in range(len(s)-block_size):` `s[i:i+block_size]` (that does nearly nothing) has a max speed of 3 MB/s. So the problem did not come from a "copy" to a variable `block`.

Comment: @Basj `s[i:j]` is still copying the data to a new string, whether you assign that to a variable or just drop it... That means allocating a new buffer of size `j-i` *characters* and copying those `j-i` characters to the new string. Also note that I mentioned *characters*, since if you have any Unicode data that means you'll use multiple bytes per character when both allocating and copying the data.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of reinventing the wheel and write my own hash / or use custom
> Rabin-Karp algorithms, what would you suggest, first to speed up this
> loop, and then as a hash?

It's always great to start with this mentality, but seems that you didn't get the idea of rolling hashes.
What makes a hashing function great for rolling is its capability of reusing the  previous processing.

> A few hash functions allow a rolling hash to be computed very
> quickly—the new hash value is rapidly calculated given only the old
> hash value, the old value removed from the window, and the new value
> added to the window.
>
> *From the same [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash)*

It's hard to compare performance across different machines without [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), but I changed your script to use a simple polynomial hashing with a prime modulo (would be even faster to work with a [Mersene prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), because the modulo operation could be done with binary operations):

```
import os, random, time

block_size = 1024  # 1 KB blocks
total_size = 10*1024*1024  # 10 MB random bytes
s = os.urandom(total_size)

base = 256
mod  = int(1e9)+7

def extend(previous_mod, byte):
    return ((previous_mod * base) + ord(byte)) % mod

most_significant = pow(base, block_size-1, mod)

def remove_left(previous_mod, byte):
    return (previous_mod - (most_significant * ord(byte)) % mod) % mod
    
def start_hash(bytes):
    h = 0
    for b in bytes:
        h = extend(h, b)
    return h

t0 = time.time()

h = start_hash(s[:block_size])
for i in range(block_size, len(s)):
    h = remove_left(h, s[i - block_size])
    h = extend(h, s[i])
    
print('rolling hashes computed in %.1f sec (%.1f MB/s)' % (time.time()-t0, total_size/1024/1024/(time.time()-t0)))
```

Apparently you achieved quite a improvement with Numba and it may speed up this code as well.
To extract more performance you may want to write a C (or other low-level language as Rust) functions to process a big slice of the list at time and returns an array with the hashes.

I'm creating a `rsync`-like tool as well, but as I'm writing in Rust performance in this level isn't a concern of mine. Instead, I'm following the tips of the [creator of rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/%7Etridge/phd_thesis.pdf) and trying to parallelize everything I can, a painful task to do in Python (probably impossible without Jython).

Answer (score 0):

> what would you suggest, first to speed up this loop, and then as a hash?

Increase the blocksize. The smaller your blocksize the more python you'll be executing per byte, and the slower it will be.

edit: your range has the default step of 1 and you don't multiply `i` by `block_size`, so instead of iterating on 10*1024 non-overlapping blocks of 1k, you're iterating on 10 million - 1024 mostly overlapping blocks

Comment: It's not as simple as this (you can try to run my code with higher values of block_size).

Comment: It really is, and I think I just realised what the issue is: you don't step by block_size, so you're hashing a block every byte. Instead of hashing 10k blocks, you're hashing 1m (largely overlapping) blocks.

Comment: Exactly this @Masklkinn! When analyzing changes between files `old.raw` and `new.raw`, it's always possible that a single byte has been inserted in the middle of the file, so it's mandatory to compute a rolling hash, with a step of `1` indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First, your slow loop. As has been mentioned you are slicing a new block for every byte (less blocksize) in the stream. This is a lot of work on both cpu and memory.

A faster loop would be to pre chunk the data into parallel bits.

```
chunksize = 4096 # suggestion
# roll the window over the previous chunk's last block into the new chunk
lastblock = None
for readchunk in read_file_chunks(chunksize):
    for i in range(0, len(readchunk), blocksize):
        # slice a block only once
        newblock = readchunk[i:blocksize]
        if lastblock:
            for bi in range(len(newblock)):
                outbyte = lastblock[bi]
                inbyte = newblock[bi]     
                # update rolling hash with inbyte and outbyte
                # check rolling hash for "hit"
        else:
            pass # calculate initial weak hash, check for "hit"
        lastblock = newblock
```

Chunksize should be a multiple of blocksize

Next, you were calculating a "rolling hash" over the entirety of each block in turn, instead of updating the hash byte by byte in "rolling" fashion. That is immensely slower. The above loop forces you to deal with the bytes as they go in and out of the window. Still, my trials show pretty poor throughput (~3Mbps~ edit: sorry that's 3MiB/s) even with a modest number of arithmetic operations on each byte. Edit: I initially had a zip() and that appears rather slow. I got more than double the throughout for the loop alone without the zip (current code above)

Python is single threaded and interpreted. I see one cpu pegged and that is the bottleneck. To get faster you'll want multiple threads (subprocess) or break into C, or both. Simply running the math in C would probably be enough I think. (Haha, "simply")

Comment: So it seems that python's iteration simply cannot go faster than this. I've written a small c program to read in a file and output a 4 byte "fastsum" for every input byte (minus the first block). This alone runs at over 1.2Gbps (reading from nvme). If I pipe that output into a python script that evaluated every single 4 byte sum (doing no operations simply doing an iteration) this nerfs the file input speed to under 20Mbps. :(